# How to cast the result of sql command to the int variable?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing a web application and in the code-behind, I need to get the ID column from specific table in the database and convert it to int. The query is:

```
string quizID = SELECT MIN(column_name) FROM table_name
```

and I want to put the value of it in

```
int quizid
```

which means I need to conversion, **so how to do that?**

Comment: Why are you getting it back as a string to start with? (It would be useful if you'd show real code rather than this pseudo-code.) What's the type of the ID column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to want to do something like this:

```
using (SqlConnection conn=new SqlConnection(sql_string)) {

    conn.Open();

    SqlCommand command=new SqlCommand(
        sql_query,
        conn
    );

    Int32 quizid=((Int32?)command.ExecuteScalar()) ?? 0;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int quizID = -1;

     using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {
                conn.Open();

                string cmdText = "SELECT MIN(column_name) FROM table_name";
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn))
                {
                    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    if (reader != null)
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            quizID = reader.GetInt32("columnname");
                        }
                    }
                    reader.Close();
                }           
                conn.Close();
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT MIN(column_name) FROM table_name", conn);

    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        int quizid = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
```

conn is the SqlConnection object